# i need to send out a blog post in chunks to google to be translated as i keep getting a 429 error for too many requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-translate, google-translation-api

I need to translate the contents of a blog post go german, but i cant translate it at once due to googles limit. I need to break it apart into chunks, send it out and bring it back and store the value into an array how can i achieve this?
![error]https://ibb.co/c6dsRfF

This is my code

```
//Sample input
var bod = a.body;

function translateBodyDe (text) {


      //IS AN ARRAY WITH THE VALUES IN PIECES
       var bodArray = text.split(' ');



    var translatedData = [];


    for(var i = 0; i< bodArray.length;  i++){


    var chunk = bodArray.slice(i, 700);


    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

         translate(chunk, {to: 'de'})
      .then(res => {
        resolve(console.log(res.text));

      }).catch(err => {
        reject(err);
      });

    });


    }


    }




 translateBodyDe(a.body);
```

Comment: I guess that `Too many requests` may be related to **many actions in short period** not a large amount of data.

Comment: would you maybe have some advice for me? please

Comment: Free services usually have limitation of requests per time. If you are passing new data automatically to Google translate every second (or minute etc.)  you should limit that time using serverside codes (or using `setInterval` in Javascript). Finally as a bad practice you may run the code anytime you want and repeat the action again if status code was 429!